# PHP shuffle константу-массив

Tags: php

Здравствуйте, допустим есть константа-массив:

```
define('constant', array('one', 'two', 'three'));
```

Я пытаюсь сделать так:

```
shuffle(costant);
```

И получаю:

```
Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference
```

Неужели подобный массив не перемешать?

Comment: на то она и константа, что не меняется. сделайте копию, и премешивайте. `$tmp = constant; shuffle($tmp);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Задумайтесь о том, что пытаетсь сделать

> Константа - это идентификатор (имя) для простого значения. Как следует из названия, их значение не может изменится в ходе выполнения скрипта

В принципе константа это и не переменная даже, которую нельзя  изменить. Обычно в различных языках программирования значения констант подставляются в код на этапе его компиляции.

Изменение порядка ключей массива в принципе его меняет. Два массива считаются эквивалентными, когда

> если $a и $b содержат одни и те же пары ключ/значение в том же самом порядке и того же типа.

Поэтому ошибку вы получаете закономерную

> Fatal error: Only variables can be passed by reference

Если вы в процессе исполнения кода хотите изменить значение константы, то очевидно должны использовать не константу, а переменную.

Но при всем этом, мне кажется, что вам вполне достаточно будет создать копию этого массива, и работать уже с ней, при этом не трогая исходный массив

```
$data = constant;
shuffle($data);
```

таким образом и волки сыты, и овцы целы.